# How do I get a handle to split_winmain

Tags: c++, command-line, boost-program-options

I am trying to get a get the boost library `program_options` working on a simple windows console library.
I have linked in the library
`C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_40\lib\libboost_program_options-vc90-s-1_40.lib`
Included the header files

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/config.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/option.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/detail/cmdline.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/detail/parsers.hpp >
```

Defined `_WIN32` (But I don't think it is required.)

And I still keep getting the

```
Error   1   error C3861: 'split_winmain': identifier not found
```

It should be so simple but I can't get it to work. Can anyone tell me what I need to do here.
Joseph Shanahan

Answer (score 1):

That function is declared in the `boost::program_options` namespace. If all you do is use its name alone, the compiler doesn't know what you're talking about. You have a few options:

- Use the fully qualified name when you call it:

  ```
  boost::program_options::split_winmain(...);
  ```
- Tell the compiler which function you mean:

  ```
  using boost::program_options::split_winmain;
  split_winmain(...);
  ```
- Bring the entire namespace into the current scope:

  ```
  using namespace boost::program_options;
  split_winmain(...);
  ```
- Make a namespace alias:

  ```
  namespace po = boost::program_options;
  po::split_winmain(...);
  ```

I prefer the last one.

Do not define the `_WIN32` macro; the compiler will do that for you when it's appropriate.

Comment: There are some boost libaries which you need to build and including the header file in not sufficient program_options is one of these. You will get the information which you require at the following website.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Comment: I understand that. It's essentially what I told you in my response to your "follow-up answer." That's a linker issue. It's not relevant to compiler issue that this question and my answer are about.